# Are there any official statements on whether Guardians of the Galaxy crosses over with other MCU movies?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1, guardians-of-the-galaxy

The upcoming Marvel's Guardians of the Galaxy is a part of Marvel Cinematic Universe. Is there an official source saying that it'll have a crossover with current storylines in the MCU?

Comment: Reasons explaining downvotes would be nice..

Comment: @SachinShekar: it might be because answers to questions about future works are inherently speculative. The easiest way to find out the answer is to wait 17 days and go watch the movie.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Not if I am asking about official source.

Comment: Sure, but your question title doesn’t mention official sources. So overall, your question makes it seem like you really want to know whether there will be any storyline crossover in the movie.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Read the question carefully. I have mentioned official sources.

Comment: Read my comment carefully! I know you did!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Why would you downvote based on just title? I didn't expect such things from you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15747/discussion-between-paul-d-waite-and-sachin-shekhar).

Comment: I’ve changed my position on this. I don’t think the actual question is opinion-based, although the title did ask a different question than the body (before I edited it). [I also think this question is on-topic](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4812/are-questions-relating-to-author-statements-about-future-real-world-fictional-wo?noredirect=1#comment12923_4812), although it is very limited in scope, given that the movie comes out in less than three weeks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**It looks like it.**

There’s [an interview with Kevin Feige](http://www.slashfilm.com/film-interview-thor-the-dark-world-producer-kevin-feige/) (president of Marvel Studios), who was talking about the post-credits scene at the end of *Thor: The Dark World* and how it ties into the wider MCU. This mentions *Guardians*, but spoiler-phobes should look away, as it mentions a potential plot point:

> **And there’s  the first tease at the end of the movie is obviously *Guardians*, but it also, with the infinity stone, seems to set up some Phase 3 stuff. Is that safe to say?**
>
>  Yeah. I mean we have… We are always sort of building towards additional things and what’s fun about that reveal for fans and for fans of comics and fans of movies is I think that’s the first time that we reveal that the Tesseract is an infinity stone, that the Aether is an infinity stone. You may see another infinity stone in Guardians and certainly fans of the comics know what one can do with all of those stones if, god forbid, they get them and with Thanos showing up at the end of *The Avengers*, he plays a part in *Guardians* and leads us towards at least one potential future.

I think that’s a pretty good suggestion that these are all part of the same storyline.

There are also several characters in *Guardians* who’ve been mentioned or seen already in the MCU:

- Seen before in *Thor: TDW*:

  > Taneleer Tivan, the Collector (Benicio Del Toro) was in the *Thor: TDW* post-credits scene, and is also on the cast listing for *Guardians*. He's also [appeared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpAep.jpg) in some of the trailers.
- Some of the [official character descriptions (minor spoilers)](http://www.stitchkingdom.com/disney-guardians-galaxy-official-character-descriptions-minor-spoilers-70951/#) also mention a character previously seen in the MCU:

  > Both Gamora (Zoe Saldana) and Nebula (Karen Gillan) have strong personal connections to Thanos, who was seen in the post-credits scene of *Avengers* and mentioned by Feige above.

Personally I suspect it might take a few films for the storylines to intersect (so I don’t expect to see the Avengers in *Guardians*, say), but I feel confident in stating that they are probably part of the same shared storyline and will eventually converge.

Comment: [Here](http://i.imgur.com/EQIaIyh.png) is a screencap of The Collector from the trailer. It's the same character and actor that showed up at the end of *Thor: The Dark World*. [Full album of screencaps here](http://imgur.com/a/injBC#15).

Comment: Joss Whedon mentions that the galaxy that the *Guardians* are in isn't the Milky Way: http://www.tor.com/blogs/2014/08/joss-whedon-marvel-movies-continuity-guardians-of-the-galaxy